# Decrypting an encrypted .ser file throwing StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, encryption, serialization, cryptography

I am creating a .ser file that contains map of encrypted Strings and their decryption keys.(I realised this is not the best way to do this but I need to show different encryption methods of the project) I then encrypt the serialised using:

```
private void encryptKeysFile() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, IOException{
    SecretKey key64 = new SecretKeySpec( new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 }, "Blowfish" );
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( "Blowfish" );
    cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key64 );
    File keysFile = new File(System.getProperty("src"),fileName);
    SealedObject sealedObject = new SealedObject(keysFile, cipher);
    CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream( new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(fileName) ), cipher );
    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream( cipherOutputStream );
    outputStream.writeObject(sealedObject);
    outputStream.close();
}
```

The object is then written back the file on the drive.
I another method the readers the file and decrypts it:

```
private File dencryptKeysFile() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, BadPaddingException{
    SecretKey key64 = new SecretKeySpec( new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 }, "Blowfish" );
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( "Blowfish" );
    cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key64 );
    CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName)),cipher);
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);
    SealedObject sealedObject = (SealedObject)inputStream.readObject();
    inputStream.close();

    File keysFile =(File)sealedObject.getObject(cipher);
    this.keysFile = keysFile;
    return keysFile;
}
```

The when these methods are run there error:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: E0F0DDB8
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at mainClasses.Encrypter.dencryptKeysFile(Encrypter.java:180)
at mainClasses.Encrypter.main(Encrypter.java:214)
```

is thrown at the file is not read.
Encrypter.java:180 = `ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);`

Comment: @SteelToe No it isn't. That one refers to a different stream header value, and to quite different code. Nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sealing and then encrypting with the same `Cipher`, which means the encryption happened with the `Cipher` in the post-sealing state, and then you are decrypting and unsealing with another `Cipher`, but this time of course the `Cipher` is in the initial state, not the post-de-sealing state, which it can only attain after de-sealing, which can never happen.

You are using belt and braces here. You don't need both the sealing and the cipher-stream encryption. Use one or the other.

Comment: Can a sealed file be opened ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'sealed file', but any file can be opened. A sealed *object* is encrypted, if that's what you mean.

Comment: So the encryption method could end after the sealed object is created, and the CipherOutputStream is trying to encrypt an already encrypted object.

Comment: That is correct. It's pointless. It is not just trying but succeeding, but the resulting file cannot be decrypted at all, because of the circularity.